# Mixpanel - Linking pre login and post login events to user on android

Tags: android, mixpanel

We have followed the guidance in the linked article and [Mixpanel documentation](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android) as well.

As per mixpanel, set alias on sign up

```
MixpanelAPI mixpanelAPI = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, MixPanelConstants.MIX_PANEL_TOKEN);
mixpanelAPI.alias("myAlias", mixpanelAPI.getDistinctId());
```

and then set identifier/distinct-id on login

```
MixpanelAPI mixpanelAPI = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, MixPanelConstants.MIX_PANEL_TOKEN);
mixpanelAPI.identify("user@xyz.com");
```

However this approach doesn't support linking of pre-login and post-login events if user doesn't sign up and logs in directly.
Alias is set when user signs up and then identify is called on login. Mixpanel recommended to set Alias once during the life time of the user.
But in case of existing user, when he tries to login, events won't be linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MixPanel guidance events can be linked if alias is set first and then identifier.

```
//set alias when user signs up

MixpanelAPI mixpanelAPI = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, MixPanelConstants.MIX_PANEL_TOKEN);
mixpanelAPI.alias("myAlias", mixpanelAPI.getDistinctId());


//set identifier when user logs in
mixpanelAPI.identify("user.alias");
```

Alias is set when user performs registration, right? Mixpanel recommends to set Alias once during the life time of the user. However this guidance doesn't support linking of pre-login and post-login events if user doesn't perform registration and logins directly (Existing user scenario)

Answer (score 0):

When you use alias with "myAlias" you linked the user with "myAlias". After that when a use login and you identify with "myAlias" mixpanel understand it is the same user.
So it should be like this :
`MixpanelAPI mixpanelAPI = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, MixPanelConstants.MIX_PANEL_TOKEN);
mixpanelAPI.alias("user.alias", mixpanelAPI.getDistinctId());`

and

```
MixpanelAPI mixpanelAPI = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(context, MixPanelConstants.MIX_PANEL_TOKEN);
mixpanelAPI.identify("user.alias");
```